# application crash in device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have made one application. In this application i have load one tableView with some text and select row in tableview load another tableview but at the time of  select row the application is crashed in device. this all  are good working in simulator.
But in device crashed.
sample code at didselectedRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
    int k,i=0 ;
    for (k = 1; k<=indexPath.row; k=k++) {      
        i = k * [appDeleg.tableData count];         
    }

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    appDeleg.finalDeptPayment = tempArray;
    [tempArray release];

    for (int j=0; j<[appDeleg.tableData count]; j++) {

        finalCalculationValue *objFinalValue = [[finalCalculationValue alloc] init];

        NSDecimalNumber *dec = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[[appDeleg.ArrRowPayments2 objectAtIndex:i+j] doubleValue]];
        objFinalValue.DeptPayment = dec;

        NSLog(@"%@",dec);
        [appDeleg.finalDeptPayment addObject:objFinalValue];
    }       

    if (objDeptDetail == nil) {

        objDeptDetail = [[DeptAndPaymentdetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"DeptAndPaymentdetail" bundle:nil];

      [self.navigationController pushViewController:objDeptDetail animated:YES];

       [objDeptDetail release];
       objDeptDetail = nil;
    }       
}
```

so, pls tell me what I do?

Comment: At which line does the debugger say does it crash ?

Comment: Also, you're leaking instances stored in your `objFinalValue` variable since you never release it.

Comment: As usual, we can't help you until you provide us the line on which this crashes, any console logging output, and the stack trace from the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Targets tab, look in the Executables group for your application, and double click on it. The window that comes up will be titled "Executable 'App Name' Info" and will have two tables in it, the top one is labeled "Arguments to be passed on launch:" the bottom one is labeled "Variables to be set in the environment:"

Click the add button for the bottom table give the new variable the name "NSZombieEnabled" and the value "YES." Then close the window and run your app (either in the simulator or the device.)

My guess is that now the app will exit with an exception in both environments and inform you which object is being used after it was deleted.

For more information: http://cocoa-nut.de/?p=16